# Continuous join on two MySQL tables using Spark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Suppose there are two tables in a `MySQL` database and we are going to run a join on them based on a common column. The point is, data on both tables are growing, so every second there are some rows added to each table.

```
Table 1:

---ID-----SomeColumn------CommonColumn----
---1----- data row 1 --------- 1 ---------
---2----- data row 2 --------- 8 ---------
---3----- data row 3 --------- 3 ---------

Table 2:

---ID---SomeOtherColumn---CommonColumn----
---1----- data row 1 --------- 5 ---------
---2----- data row 2 --------- 3 ---------
---3----- data row 3 --------- 8 ---------
```

If we simply load both tables inside `Spark` and make Spark join or make join on them inside `MySQL` and then load the result, everytime we run the program we are probably getting different results as data won't be the same. On the other hand, using `CDC` (Change Data Capture) and `Spark Streaming` cannot be the solution because we don't have all rows.

Do you have any idea how can I solve this?

Regards,